# recursion and object recreation

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to python and I am curious to why this error is occurring. This error only occurs when I input a number (`selection`) greater than 3. When the input is 1,2, or 3 it works as if it is supposed to

error:

```
  File "/Users/username/Development/foodcalc/interface.py", line 12, in display_options
    display_options()
NameError: global name 'display_options' is not defined
```

code

```
from interface import Interface

interface = Interface();

print "welcome"
print "what would you like to do?"

interface.display_options()
```

my `interface.py`

```
class Interface:
    #options = ["1 - create a meal plan","2 - add food","3 - look up food"]

    def display_options(self):
        options = ["1 - create a meal plan","2 - add food","3 - look up food"]
        for choice in options:
            print choice

        selection = int(raw_input())
        if selection > 3:
            print "Incorrect selection. Please try again."
            display_options()
        else: 
            if selection == 1:
                print "meal"
            elif selection == 2:
                print "add"
            else: 
                print "search"
```

Comment: You want `self.display_options` in the inner call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attempt to call a member function or method you need to preface it with `self.`.  Otherwise the interpreter looks for a global function with the name you've requested.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you didn't use an instance to call the function. add `self.` in-front of the function.

As a side note; it would be better to implement this in a while loop seeing as a continuous entry of incorrect values will cause your program to crash due to reaching the recursion limit.

To prevent this bug, consider writing the function like this:

```
def display_options(self):
    options = ["1 - create a meal plan","2 - add food","3 - look up food"]
    selection = 0
    while selection > len(options) or selection <= 0:
        for choice in options:
            print choice
        try:
            selection = int(raw_input())
            if selection > len(options) or selection <= 0:
                raise Exception()
        except:
            print "Incorrect selection. Please try again."

    if selection == 1:
        print "meal"
    elif selection == 2:
        print "add"
    else: 
        print "search"
```